# the Navigation that facebook app is using

Tags: android

You must have used the facebook android app. I want to implement  the same navigation that the facebook is using like: 
on swipping left the menu is opened and swipping right the chat list is shown. And in the middle the activities and layouts keep on changing. But I am confused how to make such a navigation. (Most noticable thing is that the middle page is half shown when the swipping is done on left or right.) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two good options.

1. Navigation Drawer: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
2. Sliding Drawer: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

You can make multiple navigation drawers for your use case.

Comment: I was also going for drawer layout. But in this a drawer is opened on the current layout instead of sliding it to right of left(whatever)

Comment: Any idea to make it ditto to facebook navigation.

Comment: problem: In sliding drawer, there is no back navigation, since, all is shown only on one layout. how to resolve it?

Comment: If you want it just like facebook, Sliding menu is the thing for you. It also offers apis to toggle the menu easily. You can write code in onBackPressed in your activity to close the menu first if it is already open.

Comment: If your question is answered, you might want to accept a solution, such that others can easily find the most appropriate solution. More here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I installed the FB app an hour ago. When you tap the icon in the top-right corner of the main content, the main content moves left to reveal content on the right. The revealed content remains fixed and behind the main content during the move.

**I wrote this lightweight abstraction based on the above analysis:**

```
package org.yourdomain.app;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

abstract public class NavigatorActivity extends Activity {
    static public final String TAG = "NavigatorActivity";
    static public final Boolean DEBUG_LIFECYCLE = false;

    /**
     * True when menu is on and vice versa
     */
    private boolean mToggled;
    /**
     * Percentage of the main content to keep shown
     */
    private float mDistance;
    /**
     * Navigator listener
     */
    private NavigatorListener mListener;
    /**
     * Content view
     */
    private ViewGroup mContentLayout;
    /**
     * Menu frame
     */
    private FrameLayout mMenuLayout;
    /**
     * Main frame
     */
    private FrameLayout mMainLayout;
    /**
     * Speed of toggle animation
     */
    private long mSpeed;
    /**
     * Width of the content view
     */
    private int mContentWidth;
    /**
     * Height of the content view
     */
    private int mContentHeight;
    /**
     * The current distance to slide the main frame
     */
    private int mToggleDistance;

    /**
     *
     */
    public NavigatorActivity() {
        mToggled = false;
        mDistance = 80;
        mSpeed = 300l;
    }

    /**
     * Speed setter.
     *
     * Controls how fast the menu frame is revealed.
     *
     * @param speed
     */
    public void setSpeed(long speed) {
        mSpeed = speed;
    }

    /**
     * Distance setter.
     *
     * The distance is the % of the oriented screen to pull the main frame in order to reveal the
     * menu frame.
     *
     * @param distance
     */
    public void setDistance(float distance) {
        mDistance = distance;
    }

    /**
     * Navigator listener setter.
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setNavigatorListener(NavigatorListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Log.v(TAG, "onCreate " + this + ": " + savedInstanceState);
        initContentLayout();
        setContentView(mContentLayout);
        initMenuLayout();
        mContentLayout.addView(mMenuLayout);
        initMainLayout();
        mContentLayout.addView(mMainLayout);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the main frame.
     */
    private void initMainLayout() {
        int hw = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        mMainLayout = new FrameLayout(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                setMeasuredDimension(mContentWidth, mContentHeight);
            }
        };
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(hw, hw);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the menu frame.
     */
    private void initMenuLayout() {
        int hw = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        mMenuLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(hw, hw);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        mMenuLayout.setLayoutParams(p);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the activity's content layout.
     */
    private void initContentLayout() {
        final int hw = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        mContentLayout = new RelativeLayout(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                mContentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                mContentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                setMeasuredDimension(mContentWidth, mContentHeight);
                mToggleDistance = Math.round((mDistance / 100f) * (float) mContentWidth);
            }
        };
        mContentLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(hw, hw));
    }

    /**
     * Inflates two project XML layout and adds them to the menu and main layout frames.
     *
     * @param menuLayoutResId
     * @param mainLayoutResId
     */
    protected void setContentViews(int menuLayoutResId, int mainLayoutResId) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        inflater.inflate(menuLayoutResId, mMenuLayout);
        inflater.inflate(mainLayoutResId, mMainLayout);
    }

    /**
     * Toggle the menu frame.
     */
    final public void toggleNavigator() {
        final boolean isToggled = mToggled = !mToggled;
        if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Log.v(TAG, "toggleNavigatorMenu " + this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams menuParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mMenuLayout.getLayoutParams();
        menuParams.setMargins(mContentWidth - mToggleDistance, 0, 0, 0);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mainParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mainParams.leftMargin, mToggled ? -mToggleDistance : 0);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                mainParams.leftMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                mMainLayout.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onNavigatorToggled(isToggled);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        });
        animator.setDuration(mSpeed);
        animator.start();
    }

    public static interface NavigatorListener {
        public void onNavigatorToggled(boolean isToggled);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            toggleNavigator();
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
package org.yourdomain.project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.yourdomain.app.NavigatorActivity;

public class YourActivity extends NavigatorActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setDistance(80); // will leave 20% of the main content in view
        setNavigatorListener(new NavigatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigatorToggled(boolean isToggled) {
                // Load content dynamically, like FB does?
            }
        });
        setContentViews(R.layout.layout_menu, R.layout.activity_your);
    }
}
```

- compileSdkVersion 20
- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 20

Clicking on the physical menu button on your Android device will toggle the navigator.

I plan on using this in a couple of startup projects of my own.

Let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps you.